# (biblatex-apa) How to make a long quote (>40 words)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, quotation

I want to make a long quote for my thesis on latex, using biblatex with apa, but I can't find the way to do that. My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % pone el idioma en español

\usepackage{geometry} % margenes del documento
\geometry{letterpaper, top = {2,5cm}, bottom = {2,5cm}, inner = {2,5cm},
outer = {2,5cm}, head = {1,1cm}, foot = {1,1cm}, bindingoffset = {1,0cm}}
% Si se va a usar dos paginas por hoja, agregar la opción twoside

\usepackage{helvet} % Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Arial

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] % cambiar modo de ver capitulos y secciones
{\large\bfseries\center}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}{} % Cambios en Capitulo
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en Sección
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2.5em}{3em} % Cambia el espaciamiento del capitulo de 50pt a lo pedido
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3em}{2em} % Cambia el espaciamiento de la sección a 3 espacios en blanco antes y 2 despues.

\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}} % numero de capitulo en listas
\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumi}} % añade lo anterior a sublistas

\usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{section}[2em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[5em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.9em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage[skip=6pt, indent=1cm, tocskip]{parskip} % configurar espacio entre parrafos y sangría izquierda. tocskip genera el salto entre parrafos en el indice

% paquetes necesarios para citar
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites, url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} % necesario para poner encabezado en paginas de capítulos

% paquete para encabezado y pie de pagina 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% - - - - - COMANDOS - - - - -


% ------- PORTADA ------- 

\title{PORTADA}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{2cm}

% ------- RESUMEN EJECUTIVO ------- 

\include{1-resumen-ejecutivo.tex}

% ------- CAP 1 INTRODUCCIÓN ------- 

\include{2-introduccion.tex}

% ------- CAP 2 XXXX ------- 

\include{3-capitulo-1.tex}


\end{document}
```

According to APA style, long quotes should:

— Add +1.27 cm indent for the entire text.

— First word without indent.

— Double-spacing.

— No additional space above or below.

— If quote have 2 or more paragraphs, the first line (for each paragraph) should have an exta 1.27 cm indent.

I want to make something like this (sorry for Spanish example):
[image: 40 word longer APA quote]

Comment: unrelated but do not use `\center` as a declaration, use `\centering`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Changed that, but it looks the same. Just to understand. Why not \center?

Comment: `\center` is not intended to be used as a command: it is the implementation of `\begin{center}` and adds vertical space and setsup an internal `trivlist` expected to be ended by `\endcenter`  (`\end{center}`). `\centering` just specifies centred text alignment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, thank you for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user574859 mentioned, to make this he defined a new "command":

```
\long\def\citacao#1{\medskip % \citacao is the command
\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\leftskip=1.27cm
#1 \par \medskip
\endgroup
}
```

To make examples for second paragraph incide the quote, i added \parindent 1.27cm, for initial line indent:

```
\long\def\citacaocontinue#1{\medskip % \citacao is the command
\begingroup
\parindent 1.27pt
\leftskip=1.27cm
#1 \par \medskip
\endgroup
}
```

Example:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\citacao{\lipsum[1]}

\citacaocontinue{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Return:

[image]